# Регулярные выражения javaScript валидация ip адреса Regexp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Всем здравствуйте, нужен универсальный совет как реализовать регулярное выражение,или пример с кодом, желательно подробный (если такой у вас имеется в закромах) .

Нужно проверить строку на введённый ip адрес, функцию проверки я написал, а вот с регулярными выражениями для проверки есть сложности.

мне нужно написать 1 общую регулярку которая даст мне возможность, проверять след условия:

1. Возможно ввести ip адрес и порт через “:”
2. Можно ввести доменное имя и порт через “:”
3. Проверка на корректность ввода данных (порт), а именно наличие знака “:” и тип данных после знака “:” будет число
4. Валидацию домена не проводить
5. Пример заполнения поля

a. 10.10.50.140:5900 
b. doc1.test.com.ua:5900 
c. https://233-1172-0.test-t.da.com:443 
d.llanfairpwllgwyngyllrychwyrndrobwllllatysiliogogogoch.co.da:443

Сам пробовал разобраться
проверяю свои регулярки [тут](https://regexr.com/6os98) , получается по отдельности проверить
 домен  `(\w+[./])*`,
порт `(\w+:\d{0,5}\/)?` 
или вот такой универсальный способ `/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\d+/`  но здесь только цифры и порт.

Я же хочу чтоб все 4 случая проходили по регулярке. Всем удачи с кодом!

Comment: вы можете перечислить варианты нескольких регэкспов вот так `(regexp1|regexp2|regexp3)` к примеру. Вот еще в помощь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093545/how-to-validate-domain-name-using-regex подправить надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если упаковывать все условия в одну регулярку (не знаю насколько оправдано), у меня получилось так (первый без валидации домена, второй с минимальной валидацией):

```js
const test_data = ['example.com', 'example.com:8080', 'test.com', '233-1172-0.nodered-t.it.loc:443', '10.10.50.140:5900', '10.10.50.140', '10.10.50.1400', '10.10.5.140', '10f.10.50.140', 'https://10.10.50.140:5900', 'https://10.10.50.140', 'https://test.com', 'https://example.com:8080', '-test.com', 'te-st.com', 'test-.com', 'https://test-.com', 'https://-test.com', 'https://te-st.com', '10.10.50.140:5900', 'doc1.test.com.ua:5900', 'https://233-1172-0.test-t.da.com:443', 'd.llanfairpwllgwyngyllrychwyrndrobwllllatysiliogogogoch.co.da:443', '10.10.50:5900', 'doc1.test.com.ua:59sd00', 'https://233-1172-0.tes.com:443', 'llanfairpwllgwyngyllrychwyrndrobwllllatysiliogogogoch.co.da:443'];

const regexp_no_domain_validation = /^(https?:\/\/)?((([a-z0-9-]+\.)+([a-z]{2,}))|((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}))(:\d{1,5})?$/i;
const regexp_with_domain_validation = /^(https?:\/\/)?((((?!-)([a-z0-9-]{1,63})(?<!-)\.)+([a-z]{2,}))|((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}))(:\d{1,5})?$/i;


for (const t of test_data) {
  console.log(t, ' --- ', regexp_no_domain_validation.test(t), ' --- ', regexp_with_domain_validation.test(t));
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, ваш ответ очень помог в решении данной задачи!)

Answer (score 2):

Придумал такую штуку. Я не уверен, что это правильное решение, но на простых тестах прошла проверку

Основная логика в том, что я стал ориентироваться на кол-во точек в строке. И если сильно обощить то я смотрю на выражение такого вида:

`(что угодно)(точка) 3 раза (что угодно) и быть может есть (двоеточие)(любое число) и всё это не учитвая регистр символов`

Просто этот  `что-угодно` немного разнится в разных местах:

1. По середине - это числа, буквы, минус и деление
2. В начале - это всё что в середине и двоеточие
3. В конце - это тоже самое что и в середине только нет точки в конце

Код:

```js
const ips =  [
  '10.10.50.140:5900',
  'doc1.test.com.ua:5900',
  'https://233-1172-0.test-t.da.com:443',
  'd.llanfairpwllgwyngyllrychwyrndrobwllllatysiliogogogoch.co.da:443',
  '10.10.50:5900',
  'doc1.test.com.ua:59sd00',
  'https://233-1172-0.tes.com:443',
  'llanfairpwllgwyngyllrychwyrndrobwllllatysiliogogogoch.co.da:443'
];

const regexp = /^(([a-z]|\d|-|\/|:)+\.){1}(([a-z]|\d|-|\/)+\.){2}([a-z]|\d|-|\/)+(:\d+)?$/i;

for (const ip of ips) {
  console.log(ip, regexp.test(ip));
}
```

Comment: у вас тру только на доменах 4 уровня..больше-меньше не прокатывает. это кмк не очень хорошо. ипишник, да из 4 цифр, но домены то могут быть разными по уровням.

Comment: @Андрюха Да, согласен, просто у автора они тоже были 4-х уровневыми, потому подумал, что у него наверное завязано на том, что 4 уровня

Comment: спасибо ответ был полезен, тут задумка была на универсальность , вы и предложили универсальный код, в конечном итоге я решил разделить валидацию ip и домена на 2 разные функции, чтоб было проще, а так конечно регулярки тема интересная, но надо делать по частям сразу сложно разобраться )