# Регулярное выражение для проверки URL js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

На данный момент регулярное выражение выглядит таким образом
`^https?:\/\/(\w+:?\w*@)?(\S+(?::\S*))(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@\-/]))?`
При тесте заметила проблему, что пропускается ввод, например, "https://://"
Мне нужно исключить подобный ввод url, как нужно исправить регулярку для этого?

Comment: @Vladislav  но такая регулярка вообще не принимает никакой ввод урла..

Comment: `let isValidURL = url => {try { new URL(url); return true } catch(e) { return false }}`

Comment: Может быть это подойдёт? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1425646/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-javascript-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-ip-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b0-regexp/1425733#1425733